# Display text from CKEditor from SQLalchemy in HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy, ckeditor

I used CKEditor in flask form and saved the data using SQLAlchemy and when I try to display the text with HTML using Jinja2. It doesn't display as entered.

Here is the code (it is suppose to be a in text format but instead looks like a source code):

```
<p>Emailed <strong>user first strike,</strong> <a href="http://www.google.co.in">awaiting user&#39;s reply</a>.</p>
<p>Emailed user second strike, awaiting user&#39;s reply.</p><p><strong>Emailed user-third strike, will be closing the case by the end of tomorrow&#39;s working hours.</strong></p>
```

Here is the expected result:

Emailed **user first strike,** [awaiting user's reply](http://www.google.co.in).

Emailed user second strike, awaiting user's reply.

**Emailed user-third strike, will be closing the case by the end of tomorrow's working hours.**

Answer (score 0):

Add `|safe` in the html to render the text as it is in html.
example:
`{{ column.description|safe }}`